# Rails 3 "No Route Matches" error With Custom Named Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this custom route in my routes.rb

```
match '/businesses/:permalink', :to => 'businesses#show', :as => :business_permalink
resources :businesses
```

And I have constructed a link like this:

```
<%= link_to business.name, business_permalink_path %>
```

However, whenever I visit the page with that link, I get this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"businesses", :action=>"show"}
```

I tried inverting the route order:

```
resources :businesses
match '/businesses/:permalink', :to => 'businesses#show', :as => :business_permalink
```

This does not work. It works if I change the link to this:

The show action exists and is defined in the file controllers/businesses_controller.rb.I want to create a custom URL using my permalink.

I am new in Rails and I know I am just missing something. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to business.name, business_permalink_path(business.permalink) %>
```

Comment: In short, if you use a named route with a dynamic segment, you must supply ***something*** when using the `_path` or `_url` shortcut. I just got tripped up by this myself for a couple of frustrating minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
match '/businesses/:permalink' => 'businesses#show', :as => :business_permalink
```

More here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3

Comment: This would still fail as it's just using the newer syntax. The named route path helper requires a parameter for dynamic segments.